# DBRider is not cleaning the data before new tests classes run, how can I fix that?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, integration-testing, dbunit

Not exactly sure what's going on here. 
I have a number of test classes that test `Controllers`, they worked fine for a while, but then I had to merge a particularly large commit and after that point the first test class runs as expected, but every one after that fails. 
I'm using the following annotations:

On the class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {MyServiceTestApplication.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@EnableTestAuthentication
@DBRider
@DBUnit(allowEmptyFields = true)
public class MyControllerIT {
```

On the test methods:

```
@Test
@DataSet(value = {"datasets/files.json", "datasets/setting.json"})
public void testGetMyDeltaInfo(){
```

After the first tests run, the database returns 0 rows from every stored procedure on the next two sets of tests.
If I run the three sets of tests one at a time they all complete successfully, each class has between 3 and 8 tests.
What am I missing here?

Edit: I tried adding the `cleanBefore=true` property to the `@DataSet`annotations but it didn't make any difference.
Edit 2: --It looks like the issue might be before DBRider does it's thing; Might be an issue with binding to rabbitmq.

Edit 3: The rabbit issue has been solved, the DBRider issue is still there.
Interestingly, when I run it on a jenkins build server only the last 2 tests fail. When coworkers run it locally on their machines they get the same results as I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by DBUnit not releasing the db connection between tests, this resulted in the next test being run not being able to acquire a database connection. 
We are still unsure why this is the case, as these tests worked as expected before we did the merge.
In any case, it was resolved by adding the `cacheConnection` property to the `@DBUnit` annotation and setting it to `false` like so:

`@DBUnit(allowEmptyFields = true, cacheConnection = false)`